# How to remove App.xaml ResourceDictionary at startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, skinning

I have a `ResourceDictionary` declared in the `App.xaml` file as below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/DefaultSkin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The problem is that when I attempt to load a different skin at start-up (using the `App.xaml.cs` constructor to load the last used `ResourceDictionary` skin) I find that the `ResourceDictionary` set in `Application.Resources` overrides this and reverts back to the DefaultSkin.xaml file - even when I use `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();` before choosing the required skin.

My app works perfectly when I remove the `ResourceDictionary` from `Application.Resources` - but then all xaml references are lost at design time.  How can I keep this reference at design time but remove it at runtime before it can override my skin choice?

Comment: maybe load a different skin at start-up not in ctor, but in `Startup` event handler?

Comment: Thanks, but how do I create a `Startup` event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `OnStartup` method in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        //...
    }
}
```

If you want to clear `MergedDictionaries` in the constructor, you should do it after you have called `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
}
```