# Cannot remove merged dictionaries from code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have these dictionaries:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Languages/English.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Themes/All.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Themes/Green.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to remove the dictionaries in `C#`. Tried these but failed:

```cs
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]);
```

I get this error when I use `.Clear()` method.

[image: MD]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove App.xaml ResourceDictionary at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420960/how-to-remove-app-xaml-resourcedictionary-at-startup)

Comment: No @RyanWilson. I get an error when I use it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Toni Could it be that your `Splash` type uses a resource that is not defined or available in the resource dictionaries that you have added after calling `Clear`? If it works before, then the resource in question seems to be available in the original merged dicitonaries.

Comment: What you are trying to do with MergedDictionaries.Remove after Clearing it???

Comment: @Lana I want to clear MergedDictionaries because I want to add other Dictionaries on startup.

Comment: but what does second string do? you can't remove something from clean dictionary?

Comment: @Lana what do you mean by "second string"?

Comment: MergedDictionaries.Remove

Comment: `MergedDictionaries.Remove(this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]); //Error`

`MergedDictionaries.Remove(this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[1]); //OK`

`MergedDictionaries.Remove(this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]); //Error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to clear the merged dictionary using this line:

```
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].Clear();
```

I then added the wanted dictionary with this line:

```
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(languageResourceDictionary);
```